# Determine unknown projection coordinates

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have some data in ArcGIS, but unfortunately there isn't projection coordinate, like the picture below:

[image: Fig. a]
[image: Fig. b]

This place is in America and its longitude and latitude is about -75.2° and 40.1°. Can anyone guess its "projection coordinate"?

As suggested by @JGH, the projection coordinate is "Pennsylvania State Plane South (3702)"!It matches perfectly!

Besides this shapefile above (Place 1), there is another file (Place 2, the same place), but they are not overlapped. I was wondering the projection of this shapefile.

[image: Fig. c]

Comment: If you have another question please ask it as a new question but be sure to search for any earlier Q&A that may already answer it first.

Comment: Thanks. But I suppose my second question is quite related to the first one, so I put them together.

Comment: Please take the [Tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Whether questions are related does not influence whether they can be asked in the same question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Pennsylvania State Plane South (3702)

Using the coordinates you provided, expressed in feet, they are [converted](http://www.earthpoint.us/StatePlane.aspx) to 40.1330528°, -075.1709156°

Comment: It works perfectly! I am wondering if you could guess another place's projection? It is the same place as above, but they cannot overlap. As a result, I think the Place 2 is not the "Pennsylvania State Plane South".

Comment: @TX please consider accepting the answer then so other know (green check mark to the left).

Comment: I have accepted it. I use [this website](http://www.earthpoint.us/StatePlane.aspx) to calculate some projection(e.g. Pennsylvania State Plane South & North,both in feet and meter), but failed. Could you give me some advice?