# A place in Pennsylvania with unknown projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, shapefile, data

I have a shapefile with no projection. As a result, the (X,Y) coordinate cannot be understood.

[image: Fig. 1]

[image: Fig. 2]

This place is in south eastern Pennsylvania, and its longitude and latitude is about -75.2° and 40.1°. Can anyone guess its "projection coordinate" ?

PS:
I have asked [another question here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260727/how-to-determine-this-unknown-projection-coordinates?noredirect=1#comment412887_260727) and the projection of that one is "Pennsylvania State Plane South (3702)". Unfortunately, It doesn't match this one.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting it to either UTM Zone 17 or 18

[image]

Comment: This projection doesn't work. Thanks anyway. ^_^